# Why is the image not being displayed from Firebase-Storage?

Tags: ios, xcode, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, firebase-storage

There is a `getData` class, with the help of which I display data from the Firestore on the main screen of the app.

```
class getData : ObservableObject {
     
    @Published var datas = [dataType]()
     
    init() {
         
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
         
        db.collection("items").getDocuments { (snap, err) in
             
            if err != nil {
                
                
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
             
            for i in snap!.documents {
                 
                let id = i.documentID
                let title = i.get("title") as! String
//                let timestamp : Timestamp = i.get("dueDate") as! Timestamp
                let description = i.get("description") as! String
                let pic = i.get("pic") as! String
                

                self.datas.append(dataType(id: id, title: title, description: description, pic: pic))
            }

            
            let storage = Storage.storage().reference().child("itemImages/\(UUID().uuidString).jpg")
            
            storage.getData(maxSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "errror")
                }else{
                    if let image = UIImage(data: data!) {
                    
                    storage.downloadURL { url, error in
                        if error != nil {
                            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "error")
                        }else {
                            print(url ?? "url")
                           }
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            
                          }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
 
struct dataType : Identifiable {
     
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var title : String
    var description : String
    var pic : String
}
```

All data is displayed correctly, except for the image.

```
struct RecentItemsView: View {
    var item: dataType
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 15) {
            Image(item.pic)       // Why doesn't this work?
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                .cornerRadius(32)
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8, content: {
                
                Text(item.title)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                Text(item.description)
                    .font(.caption)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                
            })
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            // Other buttons
            
            Button(action: {}, label: {
                
                Image(systemName: "0.circle.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.black))
                    .padding()
                
            })
            .padding(.trailing, -20)
            
            // Here will be numerical graduation of item
            Button(action: {}, label: {
                
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.orange))
                    .background(Color(.orange).opacity(0.2))
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .padding()
                
            })
            
        }
        
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
    
}
```

Firestore has a collection `items` with all the fields required in the document, the `pic` field has the value of the path in `Storage`. *(see Image 1)*

[image: Image 1]

**So what the problem actually?**

Comment: Because your image isn't local -- it's in firebase. Your sending a String to `Image`, which just tries to load it locally. To show the remote image, you need to get the download URL from storage, then pass that to something like `AsyncImage`

Comment: @jnpdx got it. I edited question. Can you tell me if i'm on the right way? Thanks.

Comment: You need to get the full URL from Storage https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/create-reference Once you have the URL you can use AsyncImage

Comment: You have to use the pic parameter you got from Firestore. You are just creating a new UUID for a random Storage ref each time right now.

Answer (score 0):

Your url download image code had something issues. You could try save upload image url and reusing it to download

```
class func downloadImage(imageUrl: String, completion: @escaping (_ image: UIImage?) -> Void) {
        if imageUrl != .empty {
            let documentUrl = URL(string: imageUrl)
            let downloadQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "imageDownloadQueue")
            downloadQueue.async {
                let data = NSData(contentsOf: documentUrl!)
                if data != nil {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion(UIImage(data: data! as Data))
                    }
                } else {
                    print("no document in database")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion(nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```